# AWS SAM API with Cognito User Pools authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

How can I create an API with [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) that does authorization using Cognito User Pools authorizer?

Theres [AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-authorizer.html). But ...

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
  "Properties" : {
    "AuthorizerCredentials" : String,
    "AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds" : Integer,
    "AuthorizerUri" : String,
    "IdentitySource" : String,
    "IdentityValidationExpression" : String,
    "Name" : String,
    "ProviderARNs" : [ String, ... ],
    "RestApiId" : String,
    "Type" : String
  }
}
```

it looks like [RestApiId](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html) refers to the API which uses this authorizer? But with AWS SAM, my APIs are defined like

```
Resources:
  Ec2Index:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: ec2/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ./src
      FunctionName: 'ApiEc2IndexHandler'
      Description: 'List EC2 resources'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::598545985414:role/awsmanagement-lambda-management'
      Events:
        Ec2Index:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /ec2
            Method: get
```

I dont get how do I associate them together?

Comment: This is not possible today without a Swagger model (the explicit route.) However, this feature and others is being tracked here: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/248. Hopefully soon we can rely exclusively on the implicit API definition!

Comment: @jiew-meng In short, define a Cognito Authorizer for your API using API Authorizer Object. Then, set the Auth of your lambda function to refers to this API. You can refer to https://link.medium.com/X6GaTwUjWX for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You can now reference the implicitly created api gateway with 'ServerlessRestApi'. 
So in your SAM template add this piece of regular Cloudformation and everything will work fine

```
ApiCognitoAuthorizer:          
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
  Properties:
    IdentitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization'
    Name: ApiCognitoAuthorizer
    ProviderARNs:
      - 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:{region}:{userpoolIdentifier}'
    RestApiId: !Ref ServerlessRestApi
    Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
```

Comment: This correctly attaches a cognito authorizer to the gateway, but is there any way to assign it as an authorizer to a specific function in a SAM template?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain you can specify an authorizer in SAM but you can embed Swagger in SAM files which can do this. It's a new feature as of Feb. 17 [[ref](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/aws-serverless-application-model-aws-sam-supports-inline-swagger-and-aws-cloudformation-intrinsic-functions/)].

I'm definitely not an expert on Swagger or SAM but it seems like you would want something like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Simple API Endpoint configured using Swagger specified inline and backed by a Lambda function
Resources:
   Ec2Index:
     Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
        StageName: <stage>
        DefinitionBody:
            swagger: 2.0
            info:
              title:
                Ref: AWS::StackName
            securityDefinitions:
              cognitoUserPool:
                type: apiKey,
                name: "Authorization"
                in: header
                x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
                x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
                  type: cognito_user_pools
                  providerARNs:
                    - arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:{AWS::AccountId}:userpool/<user_pool_id>
            paths:
              "/ec2":
                get:
                  security:
                    - cognitoUserPool: []
                  x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                    httpMethod: POST
                    type: aws_proxy
                    uri:
                      Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Ec2IndexLamb.Arn}/invocations
                  responses: {}
            swagger: '2.0'
   Ec2IndexLamb:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: ec2/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ./src
      FunctionName: 'ApiEc2IndexHandler'
      Description: 'List EC2 resources'
      Timeout: 30
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::598545985414:role/awsmanagement-lambda-management'
      Events:
        Ec2Index:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /ec2
            Method: get
```

---

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html#apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/inline_swagger/template.yaml

---

Edit: Fixed Swagger 2.0 syntax for the 'security' section, it should be a list.

Answer (score 3):

Since AWS SAM v1.8.0, you can do it using the following syntax. You can refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@jun711.g/aws-api-gateway-authorization-access-control-with-iam-cognito-or-lambda-authorizer-2394e7b14010?postPublishedType=initial) for more information.

In short, define a Cognito Authorizer for your API using [API Authorizer Object](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api-auth-object). Then, set the Auth of your lambda function to refers to this API.

```
MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Prod
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuth # OPTIONAL
      Authorizers:
        MyCognitoAuth:
          # Can also accept an array
          UserPoolArn: !GetAtt MyCognitoUserPool.Arn 
          Identity: # OPTIONAL
            # OPTIONAL; Default: 'Authorization'
            Header: MyAuthorizationHeader 
            # OPTIONAL
            ValidationExpression: myAuthValidationExp
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: MyFunction
    ...
    Events:
      Post:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /compute
          Method: POST
          RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
          Auth:
            Authorizer: MyCognitoAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

As @simones mentioned, the following will create the Cognito User Pool authorizer (CF template).

```
ApiCognitoAuthorizer:          
 Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
 Properties:
  IdentitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization'
  Name: ApiCognitoAuthorizer
  ProviderARNs:
   - 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:{region}:{userpoolIdentifier}'
  RestApiId: !Ref ServerlessRestApi
  Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
```

To attach it to a resource method, the following works (in Swagger file):

```
 securityDefinitions:
  ApiCognitoAuthorizer:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
    x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
      type: cognito_user_pools
      providerARNs:
        - arn:aws:cognito-idp:{region}:{userpoolIdentifier}
```

Then, add to specific methods (in Swagger file):

```
    security:
    - ApiCognitoAuthorizer: []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your Cognito User Authorizer directly to your SAM `AWS::Serverless::Api`.

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyCognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: 'arn:aws:cognito-.....' # YOUR COGNITO USER POOL ARN
```

and on your `AWS::Serverless::Function` you can add a function authorizer if you have not set the default one. Or you can deactivate it using `Authorizer: 'NONE'`.

```
Auth:
  Authorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
```

see also [documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi).

Comment: Why do you need the Authorized in the Function? Is that necessary or just creating an authorizer in the API is enough?

Comment: Adding `Authorizer` key in function is not really necessary if you add it to  the API resource. But, remember to add `RestApiId` to the function.